# Preventing a user from using any other applications when the program prompts something?

Tags: java, macos, lockout

Essentially, when running the application, the program would force the user to do something when a prompt pops up before they can do anything else. How would one do this?

Comment: You mean they can't even command-tab out of your app?

Comment: Oh ... you mean, like send you some BitCoins?  Seriously though if OSX allowed an application to take control like that, there would be something seriously wrong with it.  I >>hope<< you can't do it.

Comment: This sounds like a testing program. There are some professors who use an interface that won't allow you to leave it during the test. You're talking about something like that?

Comment: Yeah. The purpose behind this would be to prevent the user from procrastination. The application could force them to answer a question periodically for example. However, the user would still be able to quit the application.

Comment: Yeah it would be very similar to a testing program

Comment: Operating systems don't really work that way. An app doesn't have access to the core OS. There are browser plugins (Kiosk for IE, Firefox has one) that allow browsers to have some control but you can still get out of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896820/web-browser-lock-down-how-to

Comment: Isn’t a program that prevents someone from using their computer called ransomware?